# Is there a way to recover source code for gh-pages?

Tags: git, github-pages

I created a website hosted on GitHub Pages using gh-pages a couple years ago and the source code was hosted locally on my old laptop. However, I think the folder got currupted so I no longer have access to the code. I checked the `master` and `gh-page` branches in the repo and neither of them contain the source code.

Is it possible to recover the code so that I don't have to start from scratch?

Comment: When you say "source code", what exactly do you mean? Do you host HTML files that were generated from Markdown, and you want the original Markdown files?

Comment: The repo on GitHub should still have prior commits, unless somebody has done something foolish and overwritten them. You should be able to go to `https://github.com/OWNER/REPO/commits/gh-pages/` to see the commits in that particular branch.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.